# Data Binding from facebook api in Angular 2

Tags: facebook-graph-api, angular

I am trying to bind **username** and **image URL** that i got from facebook api after login via facebook to html in angular2 template but it does not get resolved. Any one have a solution for that,

facbooklogin.component.ts

```
      FB.api('/me',function(response){
            this.username= response.name;
      });

      FB.api(
        "/"+resp.authResponse.userID+"/picture",
        function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            this.profileImg=response.data.url;
        }
      });
```

facebooklogin.component.html

```
<img  *ngIf="authorized" [src]="profileImg">
            <h2>Hello {{username}}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your usernname and imageurl are in different context.  Use arrow functions.

```
FB.api('/me',(response)=>{
            this.username= response.name;
});
```